# Understanding android classes and methods

Tags: java, android

Can you explain the following code. 
I do understand classes , methods in JAVA. I am not able to understand this in android.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
  }
```

Comment: see this post http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: if you do in fact understand java classes and methods then you would understand this, its a class with a method

Comment: He probably understand Java, but is not familiar with overriding a class method as if it was a template and that's the way Android's components are coded.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a +1 to avoid your question to be taken for a wrong one. It's actually a valid one.

What you probably don't understand it's the design pattern Android uses to create most if it's  components. If you have a Java background you are then familiar with instantianting an object and changing their properties like:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame()
f.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
f.setVisible(true)
// etc
```

Android's design pattern is a bit different. I'd call it **Template/Inheritance** since most of the time you're going to be subclassing android components, **BUT ALSO OVERRIDING IT'S DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION** like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

You're actually inheriting a template (In this case `Activity`) and then adding your own logic inside the template.

To understand what does this method does, you do need to read the documentation so you learn what are they used for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

So, now to answer your ACTUAL question, the class `Activity`, when instantiated, calls `onCreate()` method. so in that code you're overriding what this method does, and setting it to do:

1. by calling super.onCreate(): it does what the default implementation do
2. By adding any extra code like setContentView(): you add some custom code to the template

Answer (score 0):

At the creation of an Activity, it sets the layout defined in /res/layout/activity_main.xml to be the main content view that is displayed by the Activity. And before that, of course, calls the original implementation of onCreate() in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` is in this case a class which extends `Activity`and therefore inherits the properties of this class.

The method `onCreate()`is defined in the `Activity` class and you override it in order to add your own code to execute upon creation of the `Activity`. You call `super.OnCreate(savedInstanceState)` to execute the onCreate() method defined in the parent class (`Activity`).

The visibility of the `onCreate()` class is 'protected' which means it is only visible to classes which extend the `Activity`class. Other types are 'private' and 'public' which you probably have encountered before. Private only allows the class itself to access the method or field, and public allows all classes to access the method or field.

`setContentView()` is a method to asign a xml layout file to the `Activity`.